# touchesBegan not called in UIView subclass

Tags: ios, swift, touchesbegan

I know there already are some questions about this but I couldn't find a solution.
There is a very simple code that works just fine on one of my projects but not on an another one:

Here is the code for subclass of UIView.

```
import UIKit

class test : UIView {

    init(frame: CGRect, color: UIColor) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = color
        self.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
        var alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "lol"
        alert.message = "lol"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
        alert.show()
    }
}
```

I'm sure the solution is quite simple but I can't find it.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: I mean that when I touch the view, No AlertView show up

Comment: tried using a simple println() in the function to see if it's not a bug with the alertview?

Comment: Actually, I used a breakpoint in the function but the app never stopped

Comment: Is `userInteractionEnabled ` enabled on your view's superviews?

Comment: Damn, that was so simple. Thank you so much  0x7fffffff♦  !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to make sure that `userInteractionEnabled` is enabled on all of the superviews of your view. If any of the superviews have this property set to `false`, the touch events won't be processed for them or any of their subviews.

Comment: Not getting desired result, though I have view->scrollview->view layout,and in both views, I have set userInteractionEnabled to true

Answer (score 3):

Maybe some of the superviews has the userInteractionEnabled set to "false"?