# touchesBegan function never being entered

Tags: swift, touchesbegan, gmsmapview

I'm trying to pop up a popover for my app. So far, the popover pops up at a fixed coordinate, I'm trying to get it to pop at the point where the user tapped. This is what I have:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    print("touchesbegan")
    for touch in touches{
        //Handle touch
        let location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ColonyPopoverController") as! ColonyPopoverController
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
        vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 150)

        if let popoverController = vc.popoverPresentationController {
            popoverController.delegate = self
            popoverController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, 20, 10)
            popoverController.sourceView = self.view
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I notice that the print statement never prints when I tap on the simulator.

I have `interaction` and `multi-touch` enabled in my view. I know that that works fine because I also have it integrated with Google Maps, so that when I tap, a google pin appears:

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapAtCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    print("You tapped at \(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)")
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude)
    marker.title = "Sydney"
    marker.snippet = "Australia"
    marker.map = mapView
```

}

and I see the print statements printing as well. Not sure what I'm missing here.

User interaction is enabled for both the superview and the view:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Googlemaps' GMSView consumes other gestures in view and it has to be explicitly disallowed:

```
mapView.settings.consumesGesturesInView = false;
```

Answer (score 8):

There are three main reasons why a view doesn't receive touches when you expect it to:

- It has `userInteractionEnabled` set to false. Apparently you've already verified that this isn't the case.
- Some other view is “on top of” the view of interest, and is receiving the touches. Note that a child view is on top of its parent (in the area covered by the child), and a view lower in the storyboard document outline is on top of any siblings that are higher in the outline. (In your screen shot, KittyMapper® is on top of Map View, in any area where they overlap.) You need to set `userInteractionEnabled` to false if you don't want the top view to receives touches.
- The view of interest is outside the bounds of its parent.

  Hit testing works recursively: the window calls `hitTest(_:withEvent:)` on each of its children (in top-to-bottom order) until one returns non-nil; `hitTest(_:withEvent:)` returns nil immediately if `pointInside(_:withEvent:)` returns false; otherwise `hitTest(_:withEvent:)` calls `hitTest(_:withEvent:)` on child (in top-to-bottom order) until one returns non-nil, and returns `self` if none of the children report a hit.

  Thus if a child is outside its parent's bounds, it can be visible (if all ancestors have `clipsToBounds` set to false), but never receive touches, because its parent's `pointInside(_:withEvent:)` will reject touches that appear to be on the child view.

You may be able to diagnose the last two cases by inspecting your view hierarchy using [Xcode's “Debug View Hierarchy” feature](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used gestureRecognizer instead and notice the same behavior. I believe my map is overriding the touch recognizers with its ```didTapAtCoordinate``` method. I wonder if the 2 are not usable in conjunction. Going to try out the ```Debug View Hierarchy``` feature, thanks.

Comment: I found the reason. Googlemaps' GMSView consumes other gestures in view and it has to be disallowed: ```mapView.settings.consumesGesturesInView = false;```.

Answer (score 0):

If `userInteractionEnabled` is true then touchesBegan should be called and your code will work and popup will appear where the user taps.

If your view is a subview then make sure userInteractionEnabled is true on any superviews.  Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443177/touchesbegan-not-called-in-uiview-subclass?rq=1)  for more info on touchesBegan not being called.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. User interaction is enabled for both the superview and the view, attached screenshots and updated question.

Comment: I found the reason. Googlemaps' GMSView consumes other gestures in view and it has to be disallowed: ```mapView.settings.consumesGesturesInView = false;```.